# OpenSCAP incorrectly reporting false for RHSA-2014:1306: bash security update (Important)

Tags: security, bash, rhel5

I'm using the following command to test for RHSA-2014:1306 on CentOS 5.9:

```
oscap oval eval --id oval:com.redhat.rhsa:def:20141306 com.redhat.rhsa-all.xml
```

The result is:

```
Definition oval:com.redhat.rhsa:def:20141306: false
Evaluation done.
```

I expect it to return `true` not `false` because the installed version is `bash-3.2-32.el5_9.1`, which is less than `3.2-33.el5_11.4`.

If I evaluate against the XCCDF file, this is the output:

```
Title   RHSA-2014:1306: bash security update (Important)
Rule    oval-com.redhat.rhsa-def-20141306
Ident   RHSA-2014-1306
Ident   CVE-2014-7169
Ident   CVE-2014-7186
Ident   CVE-2014-7187
Result  pass
```

But my version of bash should not pass. If I test for the [Shellshock vulnerability](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223), I get this:

```
# env 'x=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' 'BASH_FUNC_x()=() { :;}; echo vulnerable' bash -c "echo test"
vulnerable
bash: BASH_FUNC_x(): line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: BASH_FUNC_x(): line 0: `BASH_FUNC_x() () { :;}; echo vulnerable'
bash: error importing function definition for `BASH_FUNC_x'
test
```

How could this be?

Comment: What RHEL are you running? Also, what's the result of `bash --version`?

Comment: @austinian It's CentOS release 5.9 (Final) and `GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Can you replicate this error on another system? Have you brought the question to a RedHat support forum (loose definition of forum)? What's the result of `oscap -V`, `yum info bash`, and `yum info openscap`? (I'm just going through a sanity check here, this is weird!)

Comment: @austinian I hear ya man. I'm really scratching my head here. Maybe it's the NSA ;-) Here's some output to satisfy your curiosity: http://hastebin.com/domoxeropa.sm I've not tested on another system. I thought I'd ask here but I think you're right, perhaps there's a better forum for this issue.

Comment: Can you try to update OpenSCAP? 1.0.8 is the current stable for CentOS 5, so you can't do this with yum. The latest OpenSCAP is 1.25, you can `yum remove` your current OpenSCAP and then [compile and install from source](http://www.open-scap.org/page/Documentation#Compilation) to see if you get the same results.

Comment: @austinian I just tried to compile from source but it looks like the `make check` did not pass: http://hastebin.com/homuqefeku.pl

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully test against the CentOS 5 OVAL patch definition from MITRE: http://oval.mitre.org/rep-data/5.10/org.mitre.oval/p/index.html

So, it looks like the Red Hat OVAL definitions will not work when evaluating on CentOS.